# How to pass or echo keys of array with empty values

Tags: php, function

New to php. Please how do you select or output from an array, all the keys with NULL or empty values?

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$emptyKeys = array_keys(array_filter($array, 'strlen'));
```

`$emptyKeys` contains an array of all the keys which contain empty values.

Comment: Best Answer. Extremely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

suppose that u have an array

```
<?php

    foreach($array AS $key=>$value){

        if(empty($value)){
          echo $key;
         }

    }
?>
```

or instead of `echo` you store your keys